# Writing to text file with StreamWriter. File used by another process

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The answer to this is probably really simple and basic, however im having trouble when writing to a file as I am greeted with this error message.

"IO Exception was unhandled."

"The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SmithsSocialCare\Login Information.txt' because it is being used by another process."

This is the code in question.

```
Dim FileW As System.IO.StreamWriter
Dim Username As String
Dim Password As String
FileW = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SmithsSocialCare\Login Information.txt", True)
If TxtPass.Text = TxtPass2.Text Then
        Username = TxtUser.Text
        Password = TxtPass.Text
        FileW.WriteLine(Username & " " & Password)
        FileW.Close()
End If
```

Cheers in advance, Steven.

Comment: Do you have it open in a text editor or in something like Word?  Is that particular folder under version control?

Comment: Nope, i even tried rebooting my computer to ensure it wasn't open somewhere. And not that i am aware of.  :/

Comment: Well for one you only close the stream inside the if statement. I dont know if thats the main problem, but it might be one.

Comment: @BenKnoble - That could definitely be it if this code is being called multiple times and the equation evaluates as false for the not-last run.  Moving the FileW.Close() statement outside of the If should fix it in that case.

Comment: @Taegost I moved the FileW.Close() Outside to no luck. I am well and trully stumped.

Comment: I remember having an issue just like this where there was no explanation for it in a logging class I wrote for a tool at work...  The way i fixed it consistently (and permanently) is by making .Net handle all the IO using System.IO.File.Create, System.IO.File.Exists, and System.IO.File.AppendAllText.  I had used another method prior to that which worked too, but I don't remember it since I dropped it in favor of this method

Comment: @Taegost Cheers for the help, it's much appreciated, turns out i had read the file elsewhere and made the close line a comment for some odd reason. Again, many thanks, it does now work. edit - Doesn't matter, fixed it :)

Comment: Well, you have a couple options.  Use FileW.WriteLine(VbCrLf & Username & " " & Password), do a WriteLine() right before you write your data, or always make sure your other methods finish off with a VbCrLf at the end.  Personally I prefer to make my own Write() and WriteLine() methods that handle opening, writing, and closing the file for me automatically so i don't ever have to worry about doing those things myself and all my classes use a consistent interface.